# Nautilus does not open a file for view when it has the Execute permission

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

Am trying to open some html, php, js and css files i copied to /var/www. If they have the Execute permission (Allow execute file as program) option set i can not open them with gedit which i did normally in Ubuntu 10.10 and tested yesterday installing 10.10 to make sure.

If i remove the execute option it works and opens with gedit.

I also set Nautilus to **Run executable text files when they are opened** in the Nautilus preferences (Behavior section).

Comment: "option does not appear in here" you mean on askubuntu? The `img` button should be between the code button (`<$>`) and the numbered list.

Comment: @pydave: see meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1332/formatting-tools-keep-disappearing and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1333/askubuntu-asks-for-human-recognition-everytime formatting tools seem to have disappeared in chromium.

Comment: you can still add images from the web like this ![images_name][1] and on a line below it [1]: url_to_image. I started uploading my pixs to imageshack for the time being!

Comment: @Rinzwind: I'm using Chromium (from natty/main), so hence my confusion. I guess the dev builds are wacky?

Comment: Removed the last part since it is not related to the question at hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand, but if you remove the execute permission from folders, then you won't be able to look inside them. (So if you removed the execute permission from `/var/www`, you wouldn't be able to see any of the files inside.)

Try the following in Terminal. (It will modify permissions on everything under /var/www.)

```
chmod u+x -R /var/www
find /var/www -type f | xargs chmod u-x
```

Now the folders should be executable (so you can look inside of them), but the files are not.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

We need to decide what we want Nautilus to do with executable text files. From *Edit -> Preferences -> Behaviour* we will have the choice of three options:

[image]

- **Run executable text files when they are opened:**

  Always runs these files on opening or on mouse click
- **View executable text files when they are opened:**

  Always open these files in your standard text editor/viewer
- **Ask each time:**

  Lets us choose what to do in an additional window:

[image]

Comment: It is strange since in 10.04 and 10.10 i could open a executable html file. Analyzing everything i see it was a mistake that is fixed in 11.04 since Nautilus will want to execute a file but isnt opening a file an executable characteristic?

Comment: I always have the tick on "Ask Each Time" so I have not recognized this different behaviour. You already found your solution but nevertheless I felt that adding the standard GUI settings help others that may find their way here.

Comment: Good idea Takkat.